# Chrome positioning bug (inspected position is correct, actual position is not)

Tags: google-chrome, css-position, google-chrome-devtools

I'm experiencing what seems like an intermittent bug in Chrome. I was wondering if someone had seen this.

I have a div that is absolutely positioned with jquery, so that the it is centered. This usually works fine, but I've noticed if I am browsing other tabs during this positioning, sometimes the position gets thrown off.

Now here's the strange part: when I go to inspect the div and child elements with the Chrome dev tools, the inspector tool reports it in the right place. In this screenshot, my cursor (not shown) is hovering over the black div, yet the inspector is acting like I'm hovering over the center of the screen. The same thing happens for all the child elements:

http://bit.ly/nEaZYi

Am I confused or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jere,

Please file a bug at http://crbug.com and give a (reduced) test case if possible (otherwise it can be extremely hard for developers to reproduce the issue you are experiencing, and your request will be most likely closed as WontFix). You also seem to not be using the most recent version of Chrome. Give Chrome 16 or Chrome 17 a try and see if this particular issue is fixed for you.